# Did Khwaja Moinuddin Chishti allow music?

Tags: music, sufism

I was reading about Khwaja Moinuddin Chishti on wikipedia and the article claimed that he formally allowed music so that it would be easier for the new converts to adopt Islam.
It is sourced from a book called "The Oxford Dictionary of Islam" written by John Esposito published in 2004.

Here is shown what was in the book:

[image: John Esposito (ed.), The Oxford Dictionary of Islam (Oxford, 2004), p. 53]

Is this true?